# How can i decode a post request in socket? And how can i send 200 to show that i recieved it?

Tags: python, sockets, request

So there is my code. I want to receive some data as a JSON format and decode it. And then I want to send 200 code to postman because it waits for response. I'm sorry for my bad English.

```python
import socket
import requests

print("Status: ON")

while True:
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:

        s.bind(("", 5050))
        s.listen()
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print("Connected by ", "IP -", addr[0], "PORT -", addr[1])
        recieved_data = conn.recv(20000)
        print("Data recieved:", recieved_data.decode("ascii"))
        conn.sendall(b"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n")
```

So I've tried to decode it

```python
print("Data recieved:", recieved_data.decode())
```

but I get something like this

```yaml
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 4: invalid continuation byte
```

Without decoding I get something like this

```yaml
Status: ON
Connected by  IP - 192.168.139.119 PORT - 38986
Data recieved: b'\x16\x03\x01\x00\xe5\x01\x00\x00\xe1\x03\x03uN\xe8"\xe6^\xfd\xa0\xb4+3mR\\\xc9\x89\x98"\xbc\r\x11m\x02\xc2c\x08\xc0\x89\xab?BU W\xber\xd8D\xf8\x7f\xe7\xb8m?x|/\xced_Tyca\xa2\xf2f6\x96}\xbf\x0b\xf8\x15\xb6\x00$\x13\x01\x13\x02\x13\x03\xc0/\xc0+\xc00\xc0,\xcc\xa9\xcc\xa8\xc0\t\xc0\x13\xc0\n\xc0\x14\x00\x9c\x00\x9d\x00/\x005\x00\n\x01\x00\x00t\x00\x17\x00\x00\xff\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\n\x00\x08\x00\x06\x00\x1d\x00\x17\x00\x18\x00\x0b\x00\x02\x01\x00\x00#\x00\x00\x00\r\x00\x14\x00\x12\x04\x03\x08\x04\x04\x01\x05\x03\x08\x05\x05\x01\x08\x06\x06\x01\x02\x01\x003\x00&\x00$\x00\x1d\x00 \xe7+\xdc]\xa3O\x84\xed\xaa\xbdn\x17A0e\x0f\xba;\xd9\xb7\xf3o\x82yv\x04\xfe&\x81\x14l\x15\x00-\x00\x02\x01\x01\x00+\x00\t\x08\x03\x04\x03\x03\x03\x02\x03\x01'
```

And how can I send response? I googled this solution

```python
conn.sendall(b"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n")
```

but its not working.

This is my first public question. Please be patient.

Comment: I guess you are trying to write an HTTP server. That is a huge and complicated undertaking that you are not going to succeed with. However, you can certainly play around with the concept and see if you can correctly respond to single very simple HTTP request. The data you're receiving looks like a TLS handshake protocol message. Everything is HTTPS by default these days, so if you want HTTP you'll have to figure how to force your client to send insecure HTTP requests.

Comment: Why do you want to implement HTTP/S manually? HTTP by itself is more complex than people realize, and the TLS portion of HTTPS is way too complex for a beginner to tackle. Python has its own builtin modules for making HTTP/S servers, you should use them.